# i am trying to use sklearn's mutual_info_classif in python. It is throwing me a error?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I have a dataset with 64 columns and I wanted to find mutual information scores or matrix to get to know about the relationship between all features. I found one function in sklearn module mutual_info_score it always throws:

> ValueError: Found array with 0 sample(s) (shape=(0, 1)) while a minimum of 1 is required?

Can anyone guide me? Also, if anyone knows a better way to find mutual information for whole dataset can let me know.

I have given the input in a parameters in the form of numpy array. for both X and label.

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import mutual_info_classif
epoch1 = pd.read_excel('eegforevent_0.xlsx')
X=epoch1

y = []

for i in range(0,360):
     y.append(i)

y1 = pd.DataFrame(y)


mi = mutual_info_classif(X.to_numpy(),y1.to_numpy())
```

```
C:\Users\xx\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py:724: DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples, ), for example using ravel().
  y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)

    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call       last)
   <ipython-input-105-7a0d61440a9b> in <module>
   ----> 1 mi = mutual_info_classif(X.to_numpy(),y1.to_numpy())

  ValueError: Found array with 0 sample(s) (shape=(0, 1)) while a minimum of   1 is required.
```

Answer (score 0):

You get an error, because the function `mutual_info_classif()` requires categorical variable for target `y`. If your target `y` is a continuous variable then you can use, `mutual_info_regression()`. See the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.mutual_info_classif.html) for further details.

Further, in this line `mi = mutual_info_classif(X.to_numpy(),y1.to_numpy())`, there is no need to convert `y1` to a numpy array. Ensure that `y1` dtype is object for `mutual_info_classif()` to work.